# VBA Excel: Limit the textboxes to a value between 60 to 100

Tags: excel, vba, textbox

I'm trying to validate textboxes in a UserForm. I'm using this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65895113/15080594) on my worksheet.

How can I add validation to my textboxes to only accept numbers between 60 to 100 using the given solution? Should I add something after the `If KeyAscii >= 48 And KeyAscii <= 57 Then` or it should be elsewhere?

**UserForm**:

[image: UserForm]

**Class** code:

```vb
Private WithEvents tb As MSForms.TextBox   'note the "WithEvents"

Sub Init(tbox As Object)
    Set tb = tbox 'assigns the textbox to the "tb" global
End Sub

'Event handler works as in a form (you should get choices for "tb" in the
'  drop-downs at the top of the class module)
Private Sub tb_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    If KeyAscii >= 48 And KeyAscii <= 57 Then
        Debug.Print tb.Name, "number"
    Else
        MsgBox "The value should be in number only!", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error"
        Debug.Print tb.Name, "other"
        KeyAscii = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Code on **UserForm**:

```
Private colTB As Collection 'holds your class instances
                            ' and keeps them in scope

'This performs the setup
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Dim c As Object
    Set colTB = New Collection
    'loop all controls in the frame
    For Each c In Me.Frame3.Controls
        'look for text boxes
        If TypeName(c) = "TextBox" Then
            Debug.Print "setting up " & c.Name
            colTB.Add TbHandler(c) ' create and store an instance of your class
        End If
    Next c
End Sub

' "factory" method
Private Function TbHandler(tb As Object) As clsTxt
    Dim o As New clsTxt
    o.Init tb
    Set TbHandler = o
End Function
```

Comment: Do you have a button or something that will be clicked to use what is input? Because it would be easiest then to loop through the controls, and check the textbox for the correct value then.

Comment: @Simon I have a button that can calculate the average of all the values in the textboxes. I think it is okay to modify it.

Comment: I have a class module thing which I've got. I'm a bit busy right now to convert it but will give you an answer later. It basically is similar to what you've got but allows to emulate enter/exit functions by checking mouse & key movements.

Comment: I used this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65912050/15080594) for this question. It worked for me, but if you have another solution, I'm happy to try it.

Comment: ahh well that works then. Didn't realise you asked another question about what my first comment said.

Comment: Catching Afterupdate and Exit events: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61855925/reducing-withevent-declarations-and-subs-with-vba-and-activex/61893857#61893857

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve that easily using a Class.  The solution you are using will help you monitor each keystroke, but it looks as though you are wanting to validate input after the user has finished with the field and then you need to verify that what he has input is between 60 and 100.  For that you would probably be looking at the AfterUpdate event but sadly that is not available within a class.
I think you will either need to create a stub for each textbox_AfterUpdate to do the validation.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I want to accomplish and it seems to be really impossible since I tried all the procedures in the Class file and it updates whenever I press something and not after.

Comment: You are looking to monitor a change of focus.  That is really an event at form level and not at textbox level so I don't think you can achieve that with the class.  You could keep track of the focus yourself in code but that rapidly gets to be complex.  So a stub may be your best option if you cannot use one of the form packages I referred to.

Comment: Alright. Thank you for the idea. I'll start exploring what a stub is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub tb_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    If Not IsNumeric(tb.Value) Then
        'MsgBox "only numbers between 60 and 100 are allowed"
        tb.Value = ""
    ElseIf tb.Value >= 60 And tb.Value <= 100 Then
        'MsgBox "OK!"
    Else
        'MsgBox "only numbers between 60 and 100 are allowed"
        tb.Value = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Where should I put this? In the `Class` or in the `UserForm`?

Comment: @cjvdg: you have to put the code in the `UserForm`. You can't get the `tag:Enter/Exit` commands in a class module.