# How to limit user to input Numeric number only in all Textbox of Excel userform

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, userform

I have 60 Textbox in a Excel Userform. To limit user to input numeric number(Decimal) only for TextBox1 to TextBox50, I need to write lots of same code as below.

**My question:**

1.I want to create a class/function whatever as if I don't need to write same code for TextBox1 to TextBox50. Is there easy solution?

2.If i want to limit user for numeric number in All textbox of userform.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
If (KeyAscii > 47 And KeyAscii < 58) Or KeyAscii = 46 Then
KeyAscii = KeyAscii
Else
KeyAscii = 0
End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
'same code
End Sub

    .......
    .......
```

Comment: See previous question here for how to use a "control array" in VBA https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65894626/vba-excel-working-with-multiple-textboxes-with-the-same-code  and also a good reference here: http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/15/vba-control-arrays/

Comment: Try the solution I posted, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the next way, please:

1. Insert a class module as a event wrapper class and name it "TxtBClass", then copy the next code in its module:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents txtBEvent As MSForms.TextBox


Private Sub txtBEvent_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
  If (KeyAscii > 47 And KeyAscii < 58) Or KeyAscii = 46 Then
      KeyAscii = KeyAscii
  Else
      KeyAscii = 0
  End If
End Sub
```

2. Paste the next code in a standard module:

```
Option Explicit

Private txtB() As New TxtBClass

Sub AssignTxtBoxEvent()
  Dim ws As Worksheet, k As Long, oObj As OLEObject
  
  Set ws = ActiveSheet 'use here your necessary sheet
  ReDim txtB(100) 'maximum text boxes to be processed (can be increased)
  
  For Each oObj In ws.OLEObjects
    If TypeName(oObj.Object) = "TextBox" Then
        'exclude the textboxes you need to be excluded from this common event:
        If (oObj.Name <> "TextBoxX") And (oObj.Name <> "TextBoxX") Then
            Set txtB(k).txtBEvent = oObj.Object: k = k + 1
        End If
    End If
   Next
   ReDim Preserve txtB(k - 1)
End Sub
```

3. Run the above `Sub` in order to allocate the event at all the text boxes on the sheet. It can be called by an event, too (or better). Use `Worksheet_Activate` event, for instance. Please, copy the next code in the sheet keeping the text boxes, code module:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    AssignTxtBoxEvent
End Sub
```

4. Please, test the suggested solution and send some feedback.

**Edited**:

In order to use the suggested solution for the case of text boxes in a UserForm, please keep the same class, but assigning its event to the involved text boxes inside the `UserForm_Initialize` event:

```
Option Explicit

Private txtB() As New TxtBClass
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  Dim k As Long, oObj As Control
  ReDim txtB(100) 'maximum text boxes to be processed (it can be increased)
  
  For Each oObj In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(oObj) = "TextBox" Then
        'exclude the textboxes you need to be excluded from this common event:
        If (oObj.Name <> "TextBoxX") And (oObj.Name <> "TextBoxY") Then
            Set txtB(k).txtBEvent = oObj: k = k + 1
        End If
    End If
   Next
   ReDim Preserve txtB(k - 1)
End Sub
```

Please, test it and send some feedback. If this year, it will be much appreciated...

Comment: @mohsin: Didn't you find some time to test the above solution? If tested, doesn't it work as you need?

Comment: First of all sorry for the delayed feedback. Your code is for the worksheet textbox. How to implement for textbox of Userform?

Comment: @mohsin: Since you were so fast in sending some feedback, I will try editing the above solution and post a variant able to work in a `UserForm`... :)

Comment: @mohsin:  Please, test the updated solution (after **Edit**)...

Comment: The code is working fine. Many thanks for your help

Comment: Just want to add some more comments if anyone sees and will get help from here. To implement the numeric value restriction in only some textbox, I have updated the textbox name like textboxNumberic01, TB_Value_Numberic, QuantityNumberic...Etc. And then code will be `If InStr(oObj.Name, "Numeric") > 0 Then` instead of `If (oObj.Name <> "TextBoxX") And (oObj.Name <> "TextBoxY") Then`

Comment: @mohsin: Since, this is not part of your question, modifying the code in this way will not help anyone, I'm afraid. Anyhow, this is only a minor adaptation. I tried imagining that you want excluding some text boxes and supplied a way of doing that. Another way to extract the necessary text boxes can be the one you've just mentioned.

Comment: yeah understand. Thanks for your very quick response and a great help.