# VBA: Class Module (DblClick event)

Tags: vba, forms

Could you help me, pls?

I am trying to create a calculator via vbaform for a user which has multiple textbox. The user has requested on DblClick happens as below:

```vba
Private Sub txtPay_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

   Me.txtPay.Text = ""
   Me.txtPay.BackColor = vbWhite

End Sub
```

Once as I have multiple textbox, I was trying to create a Class Module to help in this process.
Can anyone help me with some ideas to accomplish. It is my first time in trying to use Class Module.

PS: I am learning a lot with you guys...

Comment: There are plenty of examples here on SO alone which cover this - eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65894626/vba-excel-working-with-multiple-textboxes-with-the-same-code/65895113#65895113  Also http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/15/vba-control-arrays/   Have you looked at examples and tried to implement something for your project?  If Yes what problems did you run into?

Comment: Hello @TimWilliams..                                                                                                Thanks for the link. I was able to do what I was looking for. May I share the code here  that I used to help others as well??

Comment: You can answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

In the Project - VBA Project box on the left hand side, select Insert, and then click on Class Module. In the properties box, you can change the name of the Class Module.

In the code window, you can enter your code,

`txtPay_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)`

Afterwards to use the code in your Class Module, you would need to create an object from the Class Module, for example,

`Dim txtPay As New (name of your Class Module)`

More information on the following webpage,
https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-class-modules/

Comment: Thanks for the post @Shaqil. It is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

I am pasting here the piece of code that I used to solve my issue.
Maybe it can help others

```
‘Module Class
‘Name of Module Class: CTextboxes

Option Explicit

Public WithEvents TxtGroups As MSForms.TextBox

Public Sub TxtGroups_dblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
       TxtGroups.Text = ""
       TxtGroups.BackColor = vbYellow
End Sub
----------------------------------------------------------    

’This code I put in the user form

Option Explicit

Dim TextBoxes() As New CTextboxes


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Me.TextBox1 = 0
Me.TextBox2 = 0
Me.TextBox3 = 0
Me.TextBox4 = 0

Dim ctls As MSForms.Control
Dim i As Long

    i = 1

    For Each ctls In Me.Controls

        If TypeName(ctls) = "TextBox" Then
            ReDim Preserve TextBoxes(1 To i)
            Set TextBoxes(i).TxtGroups = ctls
            i = i + 1
        End If

    Next ctls

End Sub
```